# Is it necessary for dead and abandoned questions that receive a close vote to appear in the close queue?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, vote-to-close, automatic-deletion

Please don't show [soon-to-be-automatically-deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/244519) questions in the close queue or at least put them to the back of the line.

Since I get limited amount of close votes to use in a day I'd rather not *waste* a close vote *accidentally* on a question that really doesn't need it; since the question will already be automatically taken care of.

I notice these "dead and abandoned" questions that will be auto-deleted in less than 7 days too often in the close queue. I don't prefer to have to check the right sidebar to see if the question is soon-to-be-automatically-deleted or not. I'd rather just not be shown them at all while in the close queue.

***Pro's of removing/deprioritizing:***

- will save reviewer effort and time on things that the system is already in the process of handling
- will be able to use those close votes on other questions that aren't already going to be automatically handled
- will be able to focus solely on the questions content instead of wondering if this is a dead/abandoned question that I'll just skip, so saves time and increases focus where it should be

***Pro's of keeping them there (although probably rare occurrences):***

- someone in the close queue edits the question into something decent and s/he or someone else upvotes it to save it (for the time being) from being auto-deleted
- a question wrongly shows up in the queue and a close reviewer goes and upvotes the question

One other solution to this problem would be to educate users about not needing to flag/vote to close questions that are soon-to-be-automatically-deleted, so they don't end up in the close queue in the first place. However, I don't see that solving this problem any time soon, but thankfully the issue is so easily resolved by just removing/deprioritizing these questions in the close queue.

Comment: There's another disadvantage to *not* closing them: Someone might answer before it's gone and thus upset that calculation... so that de-priorization might be a bad idea unless the roomba will get it near-immediately.

Comment: @Deduplicator Well, that's a valid concern. Not sure what the *best* time-frame would be, but since close votes don't age away till 14 days or whatever , I'd be fine with anything up to less than 7 days till auto-deleted. Then if the question ends up with an answer or an upvote to stop it from being roomba'd then just put those questions to the front of the line in close queue after the roomba script runs? I doubt there'd be that many of them, so bumping them to the front probably won't be too obvious/hectic.

Comment: Perhaps a special marker in that queue could help to identify which questions will be auto-burned so you can more easily choose to avoid them? The system can keep working the way it does, and you have your tool to manage your close votes with more care. I don't really see how any user education would be needed; if you amass enough points that you can close vote, I hope you understand how things work ;)

Comment: You could write a user script which automatically skips those questions based on the roomba criterias.

Comment: The number of views the question is getting should be taken into account somehow.     (No views and about to be deleted = pointless to put in close queue.)

Comment: Maybe they should add a "Let It Burn" button that is essentially the same as "Do Nothing," but with the effect that it turns in to a close vote if someone adds an answer or upvotes? Also optionally plays an Adele clip.

Comment: @reirab: That would probably be a major feature.  At the very least, they'd have to deal with the possibility of casting too many votes in one day (if e.g. you cast lots of "Let it Burn" votes and then all the questions get resurrected).

Comment: @Kevin What if reviewers were allowed unlimited "Let it Burn" votes?

Comment: @Deduplicator why would someone providing an answer be a bad thing such that automatic deletion would be preferable?

Comment: @MartinSmith: We aren't talking about allowing automatic deletion of questions with answers, but about tweaking the priority in the CV-queue.  And if that change leaves questions which should be closed open long enough to be pinned by an answer, pre-supposing the answer is not a really remarkable exception (why then no edit to the question?!?), it just decreases SNR.

Answer (score 14):

Would a big, fat "x days until this is automatically deleted" notice be worth considering? This would immediately put you in a mindset that you probably shouldn't spend too much time on it. You could just give it a quick glance, and if you don't spot some kind of saving grace quickly, you can move on without having wasted much time or your votes. This would also mitigate the two rare situations you mentioned.

On the other hand, this might also motivate poorly behaved reviewers (I can't think of a better phrase right now) to take action to prevent their deletion. Whether that concern is big enough to warrant much consideration, I couldn't say.

Comment: Most bad reviewers are not *actively* malicious, merely foolish, hasty, inconsistent, or uncaring. It's pretty rare, as I understand it, for someone to deliberately use review queues to try to make the site worse. Now, occasionally someone might stumble on a question they're connected to in some way that they have impure motives for trying to save, but I think that's an acceptable risk; *their own* posts will not be shown to them, of course, so that only leaves questions they themselves answered, but if those are Roomba-eligible there's almost certainly no rep loss to consider.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I think my note about "poorly behaved reviewers" was meant to be about the "foolish, hasty, inconsistent, or uncaring."

Comment: OK, but those reviewers will usually not take any extra action they don't strictly have to to process review items. They're not going to open the post in a new tab and upvote it just to make sure it's not Roomba'd; they don't care enough for that. If it's not in a dialog with options right there in review, it doesn't happen.

Comment: @NathanTuggy That is exactly the type of feedback I was hoping to get in response to that note in the answer. Thanks. =)

Answer (score 5):

The fact that someone visited, and then close-voted a question means that it might be old, but not abandoned. I don't see a reason to handle such a question differently than recent bad questions.